# Determining the space used by library functions in C

Tags: c, header

I have a bunch of code I need to analyse that I don't know how to do.  I have a pile of code that here and there are using math functions from a header file I have included called math.h that came with my IDE.  I am being asked to see how much space is used to include this.  Specifically is the compiler including all of the library functions or just the ones we use.  There is no object file being created.  So I think the library code is being compiled into the individual files.  Any ideas of a slick way to figure this out?  I can't just comment out the includes because then the code wont complie and I won't know a size and if I comment out all the lines that use math functions it is not really representative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `objdump` command to see the individual symbols inside your object files and the space they require.

Note that unless you're doing static compilation, library methods aren't generally copied into your produced binary, but only referenced (and brought in via the dynamic linker when your program is loaded).

As `math.h` is part of the standard C library, a copy of that library is basically guaranteed to always be in memory, so the additional memory and space requirements on dynamic linking are minimal. (During static linking, all symbols which aren't directly required by your program are discarded, and math functions don't tend to be very big, so usage should be fairly minimal there too).

Comment: where do I use that command?  Is that something I add to the build flow?  I believe I am using a static build but I will check on that.

Comment: @user1054210 objdump is part of GNU binutils, which will be installed and available from the command line on any reasonable (ie. non-Windows) machine with a development toolchain installed.

Comment: LOL I am using a win 7 developer tool.  I am working on an embedded system for win 8 machines...Doh.  I program in 7 and debug in 8...but I will try to see if that runs from the command line on my 7 machine. -thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code in the header file is being complied into the object file of the .c you are using if your header has the definitions of the functions and just being referenced to if they are simply the declarations.  The linker will then find a definition for each symbol and place it in your executable if you are using dynamic linking the OS will pull in the definition at run time.

Comment: So the deal is I need to prove the OTHER math functions are not being compiled into my files.  So I was thinking I could add, lets 50, lines of code that uses the same math function and variables and compile then do the same with 50 different math functions and I should see the size go up even if I reuse the same variables.  Then that proves (if I am using new functions not used anywhere else) that only used ones get added...or is there a better way?

Comment: There is not a supper good way to do that.  Especially once you consider optimization which may inline your calls. From my understand no calls you don't make get added to your objects. and you can tell this becasue you can add a declaration for a function and not call it and you will not get a linker error.

Comment: @user1054210 any sane static linker will only include the functions you use, and the functions they use. Unused things will not be copied into your binaries during static linking. (If you find a linker where they are, the people who built your toolchain need to be shot).

Comment: I agree just doing what the boss man wants.  We need to sqeeze everything out of this, power, size... We may even remove floating point stuff and man handel it all in integers.  We are doing a bunch of trig right now that we need to optimize.

Comment: @user1054210 I would look at size optimations in your compiler and linker first then before going to extremes.  Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448735.aspx or http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html for gcc

Comment: I did that first.  turning that on found new errors that the compiler should have found (really warnings but still).  I think it is not a matter of if it is how much.  Our customers want to use smaller sized parts for NVM.